# Javascript How to display current image index and total amount of images

Tags: javascript

I have made an simple `javascript` image slider which works fine so far, but I need to add some kind of counter, which indicates the number of the current slide and the amount of total slides but I don't know how to solve that.

here is my script:

```
function imageSlider(){

  let sliderElm = document.querySelector(".image-slider");
  let sliderImg = sliderElm.querySelectorAll('img');

  for(var i = 0; i < sliderImg.length; i++) {
    // I GUESS I HAVE TO DO SOME KIND OF LOOP
  }

  let totalImages = sliderImg.length;
  let totalCounter = document.getElementById('totalImages');
  totalCounter.innerHTML = totalImages; 

  document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', onNextClick);
  document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', onPreviousClick);

  function onNextClick(e) {
     let imgWidth = sliderElm.offsetWidth;
     sliderElm.scrollLeft += imgWidth;
  }

  function onPreviousClick() {
     let imgWidth = sliderElm.offsetWidth;
     sliderElm.scrollLeft -= imgWidth;
  }
}

imageSlider();
```

the basic html structure is:

```
<div class="image-slider">

  <img src="some/image.png" />
  <img src="some/image.png" />
  <img src="some/image.png" />

</div>
<div>
   <span id="currentImage"> </span> / <span id="totalImages"></span>
</div>
```

Can someone help me out

Comment: how about let currentImage = 0 (init value). When you call onNextClick() just plus one to it ?

Comment: You can use ```document.getElementsByTagName("img").length``` to get total number of images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your current image index in a variable and edit it on prev/next click handlers

```
    let imageIndex = 1

function setCurrentImageIndex(index) { 
   imageIndex = index; 
   document.getElementById('currentImage').innerText = currentIndex; 
}


function onNextClick(e) {
     let imgWidth = sliderElm.offsetWidth;
     sliderElm.scrollLeft += imgWidth;
     setCurrentImageIndex(Math.min(totalImages, imageIndex + 1));
  }

function onPreviousClick() {
     let imgWidth = sliderElm.offsetWidth;
     sliderElm.scrollLeft -= imgWidth;
     setCurrentImageIndex(Math.max(imageIndex - 1, 1));
  }
```

Comment: This is very nice! :-)

Comment: Well, glad I could help :).

Answer (score 1):

Create a `currentImage` variable to track which index you're at. Start it at `0`, and increment or decrement it on each button click. Update the `scrollLeft` and the `#currentImage` element accordingly.

Other notes,

- use `element.textContent` instead of `element.innerHTML`.
- use plural var names for arrays (e.g. `sliderImgs`)
- use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`
- use single quotes instead of double quotes in JS
- Use obvious naming; e.g. `initializeImageSlider` is clearer than `imageSlider` which could mean a number of things.

```js
function initializeImageSlider() {

  let sliderElm = document.querySelector('.image-slider');
  let sliderImgs = sliderElm.querySelectorAll('img');

  let currentImage = 0;
  let currentCounter = document.getElementById('currentImage');
  currentCounter.textContent = currentImage + 1;

  let totalImages = sliderImgs.length;
  let totalCounter = document.getElementById('totalImages');
  totalCounter.textContent = totalImages;

  document.querySelector('.next').addEventListener('click', onNextClick);
  document.querySelector('.prev').addEventListener('click', onPreviousClick);

  function onNextClick() {
    scroll(1);
  }

  function onPreviousClick() {
    scroll(-1);
  }

  function scroll(change) {
    currentImage = (currentImage + change + totalImages) % totalImages;
    let imgWidth = sliderElm.offsetWidth;
    sliderElm.scrollLeft = currentImage * imgWidth;
    currentCounter.textContent = currentImage + 1;
  }
}

initializeImageSlider();
```

```css
.image-slider,
img {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.image-slider {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-slider">
  <img src="https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/mountains-under-mist-morning-amazing-260nw-1725825019.jpg" />
  <img src="https://st.depositphotos.com/1428083/2946/i/600/depositphotos_29460297-stock-photo-bird-cage.jpg" />
  <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/environment-earth-day-hands-trees-growing-seedlings-bokeh-green-background-female-hand-holding-tree-nature-field-gra-130247647.jpg" />
</div>
<div>
  <span id="currentImage"> </span> / <span id="totalImages"></span>
</div>
<button class="prev">prev</button>
<button class="next">next</button>
```

Comment: Also a pretty nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

can't u use i as the counter? Because

```
for(var i = 0; i < sliderImg.length; i++) {
console.log(i) }
```

then u know the amount of images right?
Because i got the value of the length

Comment: yeah, but I also need to display the index of the current image... thats my main issue

Comment: Then add an event listener to the click, on click update to the current image index.

so create and query selector on a class or id, update the value on click. Does the slider ramomize the images?